# Could be closed tkinter simpledialog askinteger after 30 seconds? I need to use simpledialog

Tags: python, tkinter, simpledialog

My case:
I need input data by simpledialog to python code. My code is:

```
def enter_plan_week():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    value = simpledialog.askinteger(title="iiiiiii",prompt="nnnnnnnnnnn")
    if value is not None:
        kw = value
        open('kw.txt', 'w').write(str(kw))
    else:
        kw = int(open('kw.txt', 'r').read())
    return kw
```

If user no enter integer after 30 seconds simpledialog window should be closed and take data from kw.txt.
I need to use simpledialog.

Comment: Basically it cannot if `simpledialog` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule a function with the `after()`.  So, do like this.

```
def enter_plan_week():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.after(30*1000, root.destroy)
    value = simpledialog.askinteger(title="iiiiiii",prompt="nnnnnnnnnnn")
    ...
    return kw
```